# How can I delete some rows according to different numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

pretty new to python. I'm currently trying to modify a dataframe that looks like this

```
 stations  level_1   distance
    6          1     0.870363
    6          2     1.851696
    6          3     2.019918
    8          1     1.261097
    8          2     1.16174
    8          3     1.261097
    25         1     1.14675
    25         2     1.83467
    25         3     1.83602
```

as you can see, each station has 3 types of level and corresponding distance. What I want to achieve is, delete some number of rows according to both 'stations' and 'level_1'.

For example for station 6, I want only 2 of level_1 to stay, for station 8, I want 2 and 3 of level_1 to stay and for station 25, I only want 3 to stay.

Consequently I want my dataframe to look like this

```
stations  level_1   distance
    6          2     1.851696
    8          2     1.16174
    8          3     1.261097
    25         3     1.83602
```

This is not my real data though, I have 137 stations and each station has 954 levels so I need a pythonic way to achieve this. So far, I couldn't come up with something. Thanks in advance!

Edit: The logic to delete the rows is different for each station. I have created another dataframe for that. Looks like this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3W7J.png)

Comment: What is the logic for the row to stay? It is not clear.

Comment: what is logic to delete ?

Comment: @ManjunathKMayya what do you mean as in logic? sorry I'm very new to python.

Comment: On what basis do you want to delete the rows. Is it based on distance value? Ex: Delete rows if distance is less than 1 or something like that.

Comment: @cold_away Have you tried anything so far? Or searched online?

Comment: @ManjunathKMayya it is based on a previous list I had.

Comment: @cold_away: It would help if you could provide it.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish I have been working on it for 3 days. I have tried stack and melt but couldn't come up with something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

[`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[
    # Keep station 6 and level 2
    ((df['stations'] == 6) & (df['level_1'] == 2)) |
    # Keep station 8 and levels 2 and 3
    ((df['stations'] == 8) & (df['level_1'].isin([2, 3]))) |
    # Keep station 25 and level 3
    ((df['stations'] == 25) & (df['level_1'] == 3))
]
```

Another way would be to create a spreadsheet containing the levels you'd like to keep along with the stations, something like:

```
station    level
6          2
8          2
8          3
```

Then we can merge this dataframe with your one, and pandas will automatically inner join and only keep them:

```
# Read your spreadsheet:
new_table = pd.read_csv(r"path/to/your/sheet")

# Merge the data, this would keep only the columns found in both dataframes by default.
df = df.merge(new_table)
```

This uses [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, how can I create the spreadsheet you mentioned in second method? Thanks!

Comment: Use excel or whatever spreadsheet program you'd like. You'd just create a simple table with the data in the format that I've shown. @cold_away

Comment: @cold_away Please mark the answer as the correct answer if it satisfied your question.